# Trying to understand class inheritance in java

Tags: java, superclass, subclassing

lets say i have the super class

```
public class SuperSub {
  public void overideThisMethod(){
    System.out.println("Printed from Superclass");
  }
}
```

And i have a sub class like so,

```
public class SubClass2 extends SuperSub { 
  @Override
  public void overideThisMethod(){
    System.out.println("from subclass2");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    SubClass2 subClass2= new SubClass2();
    subClass2.overideThisMethod();
    SuperSub superSub = new SuperSub();
    superSub.overideThisMethod();
  }
}
```

I get the output from when i run the program:

```
run:
from subclass2
Printed from Superclass
```

Should the output not instead be,

```
run:
from subclass2
from subclass2
```

Any clarification is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You forgot to create a subclass object instead of a superclass object when assigning to a superclass reference.

Comment: @rgettman yes, you are right my friend thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending (also called inheritance) **does not modifies the super class**, but actually **creates a new one with the extensions you define**, like the override there.

So, both classes exist, each with its own logic.

Here, you are creating a class called `SuperSub` that prints "Printed from Superclass". Then you are using that as a base to create another class `SubClass2`, which "masks" (a.k.a. overrides) the base behavior, in this case by printing "from subclass2" instead.

That way, if you create an object of class **SuperSub**, it will still behave as **SuperSub**. 
Respectively, if you create an object of class **SubClass2**, it will behave like **SuperSub** with the "extensions" you define in **SubClass2** (in this case the overridden behavior).

Answer (score 2):

In the case of your example, the `SubClass2` class extends `SuperSub`, meaning all methods called by an instance `SuperSub2` will be functionally the same as those called by an instance `SuperSub` except for those which you've overwritten.

In the case of the variable `subClass2` it is an instance of `SubClass2` meaning it can call all methods of `SuperSub` as well as those of `SubClass2`.

For a method that exists in both classes, in your case `overideThisMethod`, the respective methods will be called based on what type your variable is. For the variable `subClass2` it is an instance of class `SubClass2` so it calls its respective method (and prints "from subclass2"). While the variable `superSub` is an instance of the `SuperSub` class so it calls the `overideThisMethod` variable in its own class and prints ("Printed from Superclass").